# Python Selenium Dynamic "id" and "name" Selector

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have to select elements which have dynamic "id" and "name" selectors, changing everytime the page is reloaded. I cant use css selectors either because the elements I am targeting share common selectors. The following is the html for the two elements that i would like to select:

```
<td colspan="60" width="60%" class="cell-right" valign="top">
  <textarea onkeydown="event.cancelBubble=true;" onkeypress="event.cancelBubble=true;" onkeyup="event.cancelBubble=true;" name="1c2b0730969c468aa06b312d96f1513b" id="1c2b0730969c468aa06b312d96f1513b" class="auto-size-field" rows="5"></textarea>
</td>
```

and

```
<td colspan="60" width="60%" class="cell-right" valign="top">
  <textarea onkeydown="event.cancelBubble=true;" onkeypress="event.cancelBubble=true;" onkeyup="event.cancelBubble=true;" name="6c5c8088fb474f2b93e1de9fb1b1771d" id="6c5c8088fb474f2b93e1de9fb1b1771d" class="auto-size-field" rows="5"></textarea>
</td>
```

Both the 'id' and 'name' selectors change dynamically everytime the page is reloaded. The xpaths are also changing on each reload as the contain references to the 'id' tags (ex. '//*[@id="6c5c8088fb474f2b93e1de9fb1b1771d"]'). And as you can see, these two elements share the same css selectors, which further complicates the matter...

The question at this point is how would I go about selecting them individually so I can interact with each text-area using send_keys()?

Comment: Can you add the HTML for the search bar? Why can't you use any css locator?

Answer (score 1):

Its a timing issue, add [implicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits) to wait for the element to exist while using `find_element`. You need to define it one time after the `driver` initialization, it will apply for the rest of the `driver` "life time"

In addition, the search bar you are looking for has id and name `q`

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/xxx/xxx/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds

login_url = "http://www.alluc.ee"
driver.get(login_url)

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id('q')
# or search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
```

Comment: Hi guy thanks for your input, but this isnt really what i am looking for. See i must use "absolute" xpaths rather than id selectors. The reason is that i'm trying to get this to work on a page where "id"s are dynamic (changing everytime the page is reloaded)

Comment: @LawlessLeopard in that case you should provide concrete example. 
Using absolute `xpath` is generally bad idea, and there are many other ways to locate elements besides `id`.

Comment: as per your recommendation i just changed the question to include a concrete example. The reason as to why i was attempting to use absolute xpaths, is that the elements i want to select share the same css-selectors and have dynamic "id" and "name" tags which change everytime the page is reloaded. Any suggestions as to how to select these?

Comment: @LawlessLeopard It might be possible to locate them by ancestor (not all the way to the `<html>` tag though), sibling and even a child. If you post the link to the that page I can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement to select specific textarea under a `<td>` then use the indexes because all the things seem common

```
<td colspan="60" width="60%" class="cell-right" valign="top">
  <textarea onkeydown="event.cancelBubble=true;" onkeypress="event.cancelBubble=true;" onkeyup="event.cancelBubble=true;" name="6c5c8088fb474f2b93e1de9fb1b1771d" id="6c5c8088fb474f2b93e1de9fb1b1771d" class="auto-size-field" rows="5"></textarea>
</td>
<td colspan="60" width="60%" class="cell-right" valign="top">
  <textarea onkeydown="event.cancelBubble=true;" onkeypress="event.cancelBubble=true;" onkeyup="event.cancelBubble=true;" name="6c5c8088fb474f2b93e1de9fb1b1771d" id="6c5c8088fb474f2b93e1de9fb1b1771d" class="auto-size-field" rows="5"></textarea>
</td>
<td colspan="60" width="60%" class="cell-right" valign="top">
  <textarea onkeydown="event.cancelBubble=true;" onkeypress="event.cancelBubble=true;" onkeyup="event.cancelBubble=true;" name="6c5c8088fb474f2b93e1de9fb1b1771d" id="6c5c8088fb474f2b93e1de9fb1b1771d" class="auto-size-field" rows="5"></textarea>
</td>
```

Suppose you want to enter some text under 2nd textarea then use below xpath :

```
//td[2]/textarea[@class='auto-size-field']
```

The other way can be locate the element based on unique parent element

e.g.

```
//div[@id='divid']/table/tr/td[2]/textarea[@class='auto-size-field']
```